# Typescript How to reference a static attribute of a class in a const variable

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm dealing with a strange situation, at least for me. In my angular 2 project, in a typescript module I tried to replace the hardcoded routes showed below:

```
const routes: Routes = [
 { path: '', redirectTo: 'login', pathMatch: 'full' },
 { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuardLogin] },
 { path: 'landing', component: LandingComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuardService] }
];
```

By this approach:

```
const routes: Routes = [
 { path: RootUris.Base, redirectTo: RootUris.Login, pathMatch: 'full' },
 { path: RootUris.Login, component: LoginComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuardLogin] },
 { path: RootUris.Landing, component: LandingComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuardService] }
];
```

Where RootUris is a class like this:

```
export class RootUris {
    public static readonly Base: string = '';
    public static readonly Login: string = 'login';
    public static readonly Landing: string = 'landing';
}
```

Everything goes well when I work in dev, even though if I run the app it works fine but when I try to build it by using **ng build --prod** I got this:

> ERROR in Illegal state: symbol without members expected, but got {"filePath":"C:/dev/myApp/client/src/app/common/url-mapping.ts","name":"RootUris","members":["Base"]}.
>
> ERROR in ./src/main.ts
>   Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './$$_gendir/app/app.module.ngfactory' in 'C:\repo\behavioral-health-legend\client\src'
>    @ ./src/main.ts 4:0-74
>    @ multi ./src/main.ts

The rarest thing here is that if I replace the first element of the array (Only that, the rest still using the static attributes):

```
{ path: RootUris.Base, redirectTo: RootUris.Login, pathMatch: 'full' }
```

By this one:

```
{ path: '', redirectTo: 'login', pathMatch: 'full' }
```

Everything works fine.

So, does anyone know why I cannot use the static attribute of my class there (in the first element of the array)? Any ideas?

Comment: That first one in the array is also the only one with pathMatch, could you try removing that but keeping the static vars and seeing if that works? Just trying to isolate the issue here. Pretty sure pathMatch needs a string and not expression.

Comment: Thanks for replying it, I just tried what you mentioned before

By using this way:

`{Path: RootUris.Base, redirectTo: RootUris.Login}`

In that sense it does not even work in dev, I got this: 

Error: Invalid configuration of route '{path: "", redirectTo: "login"}': please provide 'pathMatch'. The default value of 'pathMatch' is 'prefix', but often the intent is to use 'full'.